# How to access external link html in CI

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, external-links

I have this Html Code in my CI, it's quite normal ...
When i run in localhost it's all fine, but when i host the wbsite

it keeps sending mysite.com/www.google.com instead just wwww.google.com.

am i missing something here ?

```
<ul>
              <li>
                <a href="www.google.com" class="drop-text">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact" class="drop-text">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

result expected is www.google.com on url my bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your href needs to be `https://www.google.com`, else your site will be prepended as you are seeing.

It will think it's a local link.

So

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="drop-text">Login</a>
```

needs to be

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="drop-text">Login</a>
```

So for external links, the http:// or https:// needs to be included in the links url